# Understanding Chef::Config.http_proxy

Tags: chef-infra

I came across the below piece of code. From the looks, i know that its setting up the http & https proxies on the nodes.

```
template '/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh' do
  source 'proxy.sh.erb'
  variables(
    :proxy => node[:corporate][:proxy]
  )
end

ruby_block "setenv-http_proxy" do
  block do
    Chef::Config.http_proxy = "http://mycompany.com:8080"
    Chef::Config.https_proxy = "http://mycompany.com:8080"
    Chef::Config.no_proxy = 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
  end
end
```

Can anyone let me know what are this "Chef::Config......"  and how to find the actual things that it does in context like '`Chef::Config.http_proxy`'.

I came across this, but this mean less to be as i am not a ruby geek yet. 
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/chef/Chef/Config

Similar searches also confirms that its setting up the proxy. 
https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3912

The below question also refers to this class 
[What does `Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]` do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108214/what-does-chefconfigfile-cache-path-do-exactly)

Can anyone let me know, how to find or read the actual thing (code) that many of these `Chef::Config` do? Giving an example to understand this '`Chef::Config` with `Chef::Config.http_proxy` will be great.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the chef client makes http calls it will use this proxy. This is in a scenarion in which the server does not have direct internet connectivity and certain type of traffic has to go through certain proxies (usually http/https traffic is allowed through special proxies).

See:
https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html

In your case:

- the chef client is informed about the proxy
- a proxy.sh file is built based on an erb template.

the way chef works is that each box gets a client installed on it. Chef manages the boxes throught the clients. That Config and settings are basically configs for that client. See: https://docs.chef.io/chef_overview.html

Example of where that config is picked up and used within the client.
https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/eb590e371b5e5d3f4d1d201dd3f58e4351116f41/lib/chef/application.rb#L307

Comment: hey, i am not looking for how the http proxies work and why. I am trying to understand the thing that sets that up using the method Chef::Config.http_proxy. In a broader sense, what are the various Chef::Config.blahs  and where are they available to be read (the codes)

Answer (score 2):

`Chef::Config` - This object contains all the configuration required for chef client to run. So whenever you run chef client, as an initial step first it will initialize the chef client using the configuration provided in Chef::Config

You can find all options of `Chef::Config` at https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html

So **http_proxy** is an option for `Chef::Config` which sets up a proxy so that chef client can communicate to outside internet